# How does Cupid's arrow affect the storyline?

Tags: percy-jackson, rick-riordan, the-heroes-of-olympus

When Nico and Jason meet Cupid in Croatia, he shot Nico with an arrow. What happened then? I mean,

> Nico had a crush on Percy since a long time ago.

How did the arrow change anything?

Comment: I need to hunt down the quote, but I don't think Nico still had that crush during the HoH events as much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the original Cupid Greek myth; Cupid has 2 kinds of arrows, one gold and one lead.
The gold arrow makes you fall in love and the lead arrow has the opposite effect.
So, I think I understand your question; you want to know what happened when Nico was hit with the arrow:
The first arrow Jason deflected and it exploded into a wall.
The second arrow hit the ground and went up in a geyser of flames.
These don't sound like the regular arrows mentioned above, so Mr. Riordan must be taking poetic license here. Such as, the "explosive" nature of love.
Mostly, Cupid while invisible, physically attacked Jason and Nico.

The third arrow went into Nico's arm and disappeared leaving no blood and no wound, but Nico's face was tight with rage and pain (and shame).

So, this had to be one of the golden arrows, to remind Nico of the love that he has been denying all this time.
SPOILER:

> Nico finally reveals that he is in love with Percy Jackson not Annabeth. Cupid reveals that the only way to "defeat" Love is to face it.  And Nico finally took his first step toward accepting who and what he is.

So the arrow didn't change anything, it just forced Nico to admit who he's been in love with.

Comment: Thanks. I can't +1 since I do not have that much rep, how do I accept the answer?

Comment: @AdityaRajBhatt: Offhand, I don't know. You can ask that question in chat or meta scifi. You don't see a check mark button under the up and down arrows?

Comment: @AdityaRajBhatt: I asked for some guidance in meta scifi. I just realized I can upvote the question, maybe that will give you enough rep to accept the answer.

Comment: @AdityaRajBhatt You can accept the answer by clicking on the gray checkmark under the up/down arrows. You can see more in the [help center](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @AdityaRajBhatt: this link should help. see Kevin's answer: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/op-wants-to-upvote-and-accept-my-answer-but-doesnt-have-enough-rep/3193?noredirect=1#3193

Comment: @djm Thank you. It was stupid of me to miss the check mark.